# How to append a 2D numpy array to form a 3D array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D NumPy array of shape `(20,87)`, now I want to append multiple arrays of such type such that after appending let's say 100 of those my final shape would be `(100,20,87)`.

I tried normal appending by using `numpy.append()` but it did not work.

**Edit:**
I have attached the link to my [colab notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1FWR9JK9Ii18xutN0x9fgm49Yr_rYE9BX?usp=sharing).

This is my code:

```
audio_sr = []
x_train = []
y_train = []
x_test = []
y_test = []
for data in path:
    ipd.Audio(data)
    i = 0
    label = 0
    while i <= 120 :
        audio, sr = librosa.load(data, offset=i, duration=2)
        audio_sr.append((audio, sr))
        i += 2
    label += 1

all_mel_db = []
for audio, sr in audio_sr:
    mel_spec = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(audio, sr = sr, n_mels = 20)
    mel_db = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spec, ref = np.max)
    all_mel_db.append(mel_db)
x_train = []
x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_train = np.dstack(all_mel_db).reshape((len(all_mel_db), 20, 87))
```

And I got this error

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis
> must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has
> size 87 and the array at index 121 has size 66

on using np.append() after reshaping, I got

```
for mel_db in all_mel_db:
    mel_db = np.reshape(1, mel_db.shape[0], mel_db.shape[1])
    x_train = np.append(x_train, mel_db)
```

Error:

> Non-string object detected for the array ordering. Please pass in 'C',
> 'F', 'A', or 'K' instead

And on simply converting to a NumPy array:

```
x_train = np.array(all_mel_db)
```

I got:

> ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (20,87) into
> shape (20)

Comment: Do not use `np.append`.  It is slow and hard to use right.  `np.array([x,y,z,...])` is better.

Comment: reshape your 1st array say(x) to (1, 20, 87), the use np.append(x, y, axis = 0)

Comment: @RahulVishwakarma I had tried to reshape it but it gave an error. I have attached a link to my code, please to check and tell me what went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `numpy.dstack` to produce output of shape `(20, 87, N)` by:

```
a = np.random.rand(20, 87)
b = np.random.rand(20, 87)
c = np.random.rand(20, 87)
d = np.random.rand(20, 87)

collection = np.dstack([a, b, c, d])
collection.shape # out: (20, 87, 4)

collection = np.dstack([a, b, c, d]).reshape((4, 20, 87))
collection.shape # out: (4, 20, 87)
```

Cheers.

Comment: Is there a way to make it (N, 20, 87) dynamically, also I have attached a link to my colab notebook just in case you want to take a look

Answer (score 0):

You need to make all your audio segment features the same size and then you can stack them vertically. Example you files are in pkl format;

```
    max_pad_len = 87 #max length features

def ft_extraction():
    for item in dirs:
        x, sr = librosa.load(path+item)
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(x, sr=sr)
        pad_width = max_pad_len - mfccs.shape[1] #eg 80 - 15
        mfccs = np.pad(mfccs, pad_width=([0,0],[0,pad_width]), mode='constant', constant_values=0)
        
        #print (mfccs)
        pickle.dump(mfccs,open(path+item +'.pkl','wb'))
                
ft_extraction()
```

And then stack them;

```
# vertical stack all feature files

audio_all_3d = []
for file in os.listdir(newpath):
    if file.endswith('.pkl'):
        myfile = open(newpath+file,"rb")
        audio_all_3d.append(pickle.load(myfile))
        myfile.close()
aud_ft = np.stack(audio_all_3d)
```

You will get 3 Dimensional shape

(100,20,87)